# proof of $p'(x)^2 \geq p(x)p''(x) \text { for all x } \in \Bbb{R}$

Tags: polynomials, derivatives, proof-writing

$p(x)$ is non-constant polynomial with only real roots. If $x = a_i$ is a root of $p(x)$,  we are done. Assume then $x$ is not a root. Product of differentiation:

$$p\prime(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{p(x)}{x-a_k}$$

that is

$$\frac{p\prime(x)}{p(x)} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{x-a_k}$$

now by differentiating it again, we get:

$$\frac{p\prime\prime(x)p(x)-p\prime(x)^2}{p(x)^2} = -\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(x-a_k)^2} $$

I understand, why after second differentiation we get left side, but I can't figure out, how we got the right side ($-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(x-a_k)^2} $). Can you please provide me some tips? Thanks

... and to complete the proof, by second differentiation we see, that $-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(x-a_k)^2} < 0$, so also:

$$\frac{p\prime\prime(x)p(x)-p\prime(x)^2}{p(x)^2} < 0$$
$$p\prime\prime(x)p(x)-p\prime(x)^2 < 0$$
$$p\prime\prime(x)p(x) < p\prime(x)^2 $$
...done :)

Comment: It is because $$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{x-a_k} = \frac{-1}{(x-a_k)^2}.$$

Comment: true... I tried modificating left side many times, forgot to differentiate left side... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align} \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{x-a_k}\right)'&=\sum \limits_{k=1}^n  \left(\frac{1}{x-a_k} \right)' &(f+g)'=f'+g'\\
&=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \left[(x-a_k)^{-1}\right]' &\frac{1}{\alpha}=\alpha^{-1}\\
&=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(-1\cdot (x-a_k)^{-2}\cdot x'\right) & \text{Chain and power rules}\\
&=-\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{(x-a_k)^2}\right) &\frac{1}{\alpha}=\alpha^{-1} \text{ and distributivy}\end{align}$$